# simple_form date input not as select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I use simple_form and I need date select as 3 **separate** input fields (day month year).

This is what I've got, but it is definitely not what I want.

```
<%= f.date_select :date_of_birth, start_year: Date.today.year - 16,
                            end_year: Date.today.year - 100,
                            order: [:day, :month, :year], label: false %>
```

Thanks for help!

As of now, I just assume I will have to substitute my `date_of_birth` with 3 fields in DB and simply write a method which will assemble these into actually date of birth, which I see as ugly path and hoped there is better one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to just add 3 fields to database:

```
  t.integer :birth_day
  t.integer :birth_month
  t.integer :birth_year
```

write some validations:

```
  validates :birth_day, 
            numericality: { only_integer: true, message: "Please enter numbers only." }, 
            length: { is: 2, message: "Should be 2 digits." },
            inclusion: { in: 1..31, message: 'should be in range 1..31'}
  validates :birth_month, 
            numericality: { only_integer: true, message: "Please enter numbers only." }, 
            length: { is: 2, message: "Should be 2 digits." },
            inclusion: { in: 1..12, message: 'should be in range 1..31'}
  validates :birth_year, 
            numericality: { only_integer: true, message: "Please enter numbers only." }, 
            length: { is: 4, message: "Should be 4 digits." },
            inclusion: { in: 1900..1996, message: 'should be in range 1900..1996'}
```

and write a method to a method assembling a date object:

```
  def date_of_birth
    "#{birth_day}/#{Date::MONTHNAMES[birth_month]}/#{birth_year}".to_date
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
= date_select 'object_name', :date_of_birth
```

Where you should replace 'object_name' with your object name. For example 'user' for User class, and so on.

But keep in mind, that such approach can break your markup, because simple_form adds its own divs and other wrappers to form fields. So you should add them too.

Comment: thx for answer! It was quite urgent, so I've sticked to 3 fields in DB and assembly method.